# No route matches for something that should be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have:

```
<%= button_to 'Remove', remove_attendee_event_path(:event_id => @event.id, :user_id => user.id), :method => :post %>
```

in one partial and it works fine. Then, in another partial in the same view, I tried to copy/paste this code while changing @event.id to event.id and user.id to current_user.id and it doesn't work. It tells me RoutingError in Events#index

```
No route matches {:action=>"remove_attendee", :controller=>"events", :event_id=>4, :user_id=>108}
```

WHat am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just a fyi you can run `rake routes` to get a list of all valid routes.

Comment: Please post the output of `rake routes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the route it is your object. You are padding nil objects to the method.

Check which object is nil with:

```
<%= debug @event %>
<%= debug user #most likely this one %>
```

Local variables need to be sent to views like this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'somethign' :user => user %>
```

Comment: I really don't understand. I tried debug and nothing appeared...it still throws an error. I'm not trying to render anything I don't think...just trying to add this button that performs a function. Doesn't it show that I am passing the event and user ids correctly in the error information?

Comment: If nothing appeared then you forgot to include the = in the <%=%> or the object is nil

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're passing an `:event_id` parameter to the path helper instead of `:id`. A member action requires an `:id` attribute to specify the member to work with, which in the EventsController will be an Event.

In the partial where this line of code worked, rails was filling in the `:id` for you based on the current request (which must have been another member action where an Event id was available). The `:event_id` that you supplied as an argument was ignored (or actually it was probably tacked onto the end of the URL after the question mark and then ignored by the `remove_attendee` method in the controller).

But now when you try the same line in the index view, it has no `:id` to fill in the gap, so it's cryptically complaining.